# What is the meaning of "well done" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sarcasm

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> The idea that "poor" marks quality whereas "bad" marks morality is truly a peeve beyond all other peeves--a real peever's peeve. Well done.

I want to know what author wants to convey by "well done" in that sentence? I mean we use it for praising someone? Who is he praising in that sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of **sarcasm**.

> The use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say,
>   made in order to hurt someone's feelings **or to criticize something in
>   a humorous way**: "You have been working hard," he said with heavy
>   sarcasm, as he looked at the empty page.

[Sarcasm (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sarcasm)